# C# ASP.NET Regional Settings working with delimited values

Tags: c#, asp.net, regional-settings

What is the best way to handle regional settings? Is it with cultureInfo in the code itself or would it be more a configuration setup in web.config?

Here is an example:

```
string val = "0.00"; //Value that will be handled over requests 
decimal totalCur  = Decimal.Parse(val);
```

Well here is the scenario: I am developing an application on my local computer and working with decimal values has always been a problem. Because when I publish the application to the server or to a client there is always the chance of the decimal separator to be different for instance on my local computer the variable has a . (dot) separator but on the server the variable wants a , (comma) separator. Is there a central solution to this issue or do you have to address this issue on every time you deploy your solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid this is impossible to answer without more concrete requirements. Handle regional settings in what sense? What problem are you trying to solve? Your title talks about "working with delimited values" but your question body doesn't mention it at all. Please provide a lot more context, along with what you've already tried and what happened.

Comment: Well here is the scenario: I am developing an application on my local computer and working with decimal values has always been a problem. Because when I publish the application to the server or to a client there is always the chance of the decimal separator to be different for instance on my local computer it uses the . (dot) separator but on the server it wants a , (comma) separator. Is there a central solution to this issue or do you have to address this issue on every time you deploy your solution?

Comment: Don't put it in the comment - put it in the *question*... along with more details about what you mean by "it uses" and "it wants". (We don't know what you're *doing* with these strings...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Globalization section in Web.config of your website to let the .Net framework handle for you :)
If "culture" and "uiculture" is set to "auto", the client(browser's) culture will be considered for reading the resource file and for any datetime, currency values.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed to know! :)